# Не работает EditText в DialogInterface

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

Заниматься программированием начал недавно, возможно, допустил грубую ошибку в использовании DialogInterface
Буду благодарен за любую помощь

По задумке после нажатия утвердительной кнопки значения с полей должны считаться, преобразоваться в String, и улететь в базу данных. Но улетают только null'ы, как ни крути. Раскладка не помогает. Тестирую на Nexus6P

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int number) {

    SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new PasswordDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues enteredData = new ContentValues();
    EditText siteForm;
    EditText passForm;
    EditText infoForm;

    switch(number) {
        case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE: {
            siteForm = (EditText) viewDialogLayer.findViewById(R.id.site);
            passForm = (EditText) viewDialogLayer.findViewById(R.id.pass);
            infoForm = (EditText) viewDialogLayer.findViewById(R.id.info);

            if(siteForm.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast debugToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Sry, bro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                debugToast.show();
            }

                enteredData.put("SITE", siteForm.getText().toString());
                enteredData.put("PASS", passForm.getText().toString());
                enteredData.put("INFO", infoForm.getText().toString());
                database.insert("DATAPASS", null, enteredData);

                break;
            }

        case Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE: {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. у вас не падает, вызовы типа `siteForm.getText().toString()` не возвращают `null` или пустую строку и проблема именно в том, что реально передаваемые значения не записываются хотя сама транщакция записи происходит?

Comment: Мне кажется, что проблема у вас в том, что вы вьюхи ищете в переменной `viewDialogLayer`, тогда как надо бы их искать в `dialogInterface`, скастовав его к диалогу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это

```
switch(number) {
    case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE: {
        siteForm = (EditText) viewDialogLayer.findViewById(R.id.site);
        passForm = (EditText) viewDialogLayer.findViewById(R.id.pass);
infoForm = (EditText) viewDialogLayer.findViewById(R.id.info);
```

Поменяйте на

```
Dialog d = (Dialog)dialogInterface;

switch(number) {
    case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE: {
        siteForm = (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.site);
        passForm = (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.pass);
        infoForm = (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.info);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Именно в этом и была причина. Впрочем, логично, что брать значения надо из слоя диалога. Век живи - век учись